# Moving XML file to be hosted

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Please be gentle. I am not a terribly proficient developer!

So this is the last thing I need to fix in my Windows Phone 7.5 app before I consider it done. In short, the data sources on the menus are driven by an xml file. That file is stored locally with the app. I would like to store that file somewhere on the Internet). Currently if I need to make a change to this xml file, I have to re-submit the app to the Marketplace taking about 5 days before the change goes live. How 2003 of me.

So I can't figure out what they are expecting returned in the code below. I've hacked away and it always give some error I don't understand.

I've set the filename variable to a URL of a file on the Internet but apparently that is not supported. So I either need a new way for that whole section to work or a way to convert the hosted filename converted into something that will work.

---

```
private static void FirstLaunch()
    {
        // On the first launch, just add everything from the OPML file

        string filename;

//This file should really be hosted on the Internet somewhere.

        filename = "/RSSReader;component/LyncNews-opml.xml";

        StreamResourceInfo xml = App.GetResourceStream(new Uri(filename, UriKind.Relative));
        List<RSSPage> rssPages = ParseOPML(xml.Stream);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set it to a URL, but you'll need to download the content, not through App.GetResourceStream. Try `WebClient`, it's easy and simple.

A simple usage:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();

    client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(Client_DownloadStringCompleted);
    Uri token = new Uri("your url");

    client.DownloadStringAsync(token);
```

and handle xml parsing in the event.

Comment: using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {

    }

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. When I paste that code in, I get the red squiggly underneath "DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(Client_DownloadStringCompleted);". Doing research, It looks like I need to add something similar to the following: `  private void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }` But that still leaves the red squiggly.

Comment: Yes, that's the event handler. Basically you're downloading content of that url asynchronously and that method will be called when download is finished. Alternatively, you can also do synchronous download using webclient, that way you don't need an event handler, but you're blocking the thread until download is over. App.GetResourceStream is for the resources that you have in your application.